# Make the variable to be shown in the chart customizable

Tags: looker-studio

I have a Google Sheets dataset and I'm creating a Google Data Studio report out of it (and I'm a beginner).
I need to create 3 filters, similar to this I did on Google Sheets:

[image]

First and second are alright, just adding the filter and selecting the metric.
However the third one should select the metric to be analyzed in my chart, so it gets to look like this:

[image]

And the metrics to be analyzed are the ones in yellow in my sheets database:
[image]

If I understood correctly I need to leave dimension as customizable variable to the user among a set of variables.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find a proper way to do that in Google Data Studio.
The best way I found was to add an Optional Metric chart by chart. It is not ideal because I wanted a single metric filter for all charts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do it would be to unpivot your original data. Add a new color name indicator that will have the column names. And then have all the values in a single field. So your rows will increase by 3x amount and you will have 2 less columns. Then you can add the indicator field as a filter.

Comment: Could you be more visual? Some printscreens would definitely help